# We no longer need to [hijack]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

A recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606847/jquery-update-method-versions-mismatch) regarding a jQuery plugin named "hyjack" pointed me to a tag [hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) and its pseudo-synonym [hijacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijacked). This seems a particularly good candidate for burnination. At the time of writing the post, the tags have the following number of questions:

- [hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) - 88 questions
- <s>[hijacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijacked) - 11 questions</s> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- <s>[hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijacking) - 3 questions</s> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?

To me, this appears to be a meta-tag. On its own it does not describe a programming-related concept. Even on [security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/) it is given more meaning of [Browser-Hijacking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-hijacking).

#### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Not in my humble opinion. We have tags related to the programming side of this concept such as [xss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xss) and [csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csrf) which have a high number of question in comparison to the 88 in the [hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) and 3 in the [hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijacking).

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

I did not look through them all, but no I do not think it does. Hijacking can mean many different things and as stated above it has been added as a meta-tag to the vast majority of tagged questions.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Not even slightly.

Comment: Only 11 questions had [tag:hijacked]. I removed the tag from them, voted-to-close most (wildly off-topic or too broad), and cleaned up the two or three that seemed to have value.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring -  Q: +68/-4

Comment: Isn't [this tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hijack/info) a bit premature seeing it hasn't been decided yet to burn the tag???

Comment: @AndréKool no, that follows the [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) on burination `The tag's wiki will be edited to "DO NOT USE! This tag is being burninated. See: <link to Meta question>" (or the tag will be blacklisted).`

Comment: @Jamiec Actually no to you. What you said is part of phase 4. This burninate request is only in phase 2.

Comment: @AndréKool right you are!

Comment: @AndréKool yes, I rolled it back.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring -  Q: +127/-6. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: Title should read `The [hijack] tag is in the process of being hijacked`

Comment: I put the old tag excerpt in so that somebody trying to use the tag to find the discussion.

Answer (score 12):

[hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance

Use

- [go-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-http) for questions related to [Go's http hijacking](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Hijacker).
- [session-hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-hijacking) for questions related to [Session or Cookie hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).
- [method-interception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-interception) for questions related to hijacking method calls.

## Progress:

The [hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=hijack),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhijack%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhijack%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhijack%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhijack%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.